# Pine Script: Paint label when two conditions are met one after the other

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to paint a label once two condition are met one after the other on multiple bars.

First the fourK-sma crosses the fiveK-sma and then the very next time the oneK-sma crosses the oneD-sma it paints a label.

ATM the script is saving fine but isn't painting the label and I've run out of ideas as to how to approach this.

```
oneK=sma(stoch(close, high, low, 11), 10)
oneD=sma(oneK, 4)
fourK=sma(stoch(close, high, low, 176), 160)
fiveK=sma(stoch(close, high, low, 352), 320)

test=bool(na)
fir=bool(na)
if (crossover(fourK,fiveK))
    test:=true
if (test==true) and crossover(oneK,oneD)
    fir:=true
    test:=false

plotshape(fir, style = shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar, color=#ff4545, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems were:

- You declare your variables without the `var` keyword, so they're
  initialized on every bar.
- Once `fir` is set to true, you never reset it to false again.

This will work:

```
//@version=4
study("SO 64706821", overlay=true, shorttitle="SO")

oneK  = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 11), 10)
oneD  = sma(oneK, 4)
fourK = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 176), 160)
fiveK = sma(stoch(close, high, low, 352), 320)

var bool test = na // Initializion occurs once, on first bar
bool fir = false   // Initializion occurs on every bar

if crossover(fourK,fiveK)
    test := true
    
if test and crossover(oneK,oneD)
    fir  := true
    test := false

plotshape(fir, style = shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar, color=color.red, size=size.small)

// Background color to make it more clear where the signals occur, because there are so few.
bgcolor(fir ? color.yellow : na, transp=80)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with the above answer - is that if you are coding for numerous conditions, and you have another condition that will change the state of the 'test' variable - then a different condition may in a way 'redirect' you by cutting you off after the first initialization before the 'fir' condition shows up.

Not exactly sure how to get around that but just my 2 cents.